# Is total boundedness implying boundedness by topological vector space's definition in Rudin?

Tags: functional-analysis

Rudin defined total boundedness of a set in a TVS(topological vector space) as "for every neighborhood $V$ of zero in TVS $X$, there is a finite set $F$ such that $E$ is contained in $F+V$". However a set $E$ bounded in $X$ means that for any neighborhood $V$ of zero for any $t>0$ sufficiently large, $E$ is contained in $tV$. From the names it seems total boundedness should imply boundedness. This is obviously true if there is a local convex base for $X$. Is it true for any TVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Given a $0$-neighborhood $V$ there is (by continuity of multiplication with scalars and addition) another $0$-neighborhood $W$ such that $W+tW\subseteq V$ for all $|t|\le 1$. Applying total boundedness to $W$ yields a finite set $F$ with $B\subseteq F+W$ and since $W$ is absorbing and $F$ finite there is $0<|t|\le 1$ with $tF \subseteq W$. This gives
$$ tB \subseteq tF+tW\subseteq W+tW \subseteq U.$$
Hence $B\subseteq \frac 1t U$.